# How to init a NSMutableDictionary object with numbers and UIImages

Tags: python, objective-c

I know that in Python, I can init a dict like this:

```
numbers = range(1,5)
objs = [pic1, pic2, pic3, pic4]
dict_obj = dict(zip(numbers, objs))
```

the pic1-pic4 is objects such as the instances of a class.

My problem is can I init a NSMutableDictionary object in Objective-C like the code above with numbers in NSArray and the NSMutableArray which holds some UIImage elements, I don't know if the key in NSMutableDictionary can be pointer or object but not only number or string?

Comment: Is your question really *"what are acceptable keys for `NSMutableDictionary`"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be. The template of Dictionary definition itself shows that it accepts array holding objects as argument for setting both objects and keys

```
NSDictionary *aDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:(NSArray *) forKeys:(NSArray *)];
```

Your answer would be like this.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@1,@2,@3,@4] forKeys:@[pics1,pics2,pics3,pics4]];
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs,

```
Each key is copied (using copyWithZone:; keys must conform to the NSCopying protocol), 
and the copy is added to the new dictionary.
```